# Getting a single 90th percentile value of the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the 90th percentile of the date difference however, the result returns multiple rows of the the percentile data. I only want a **single row stating the 90th percentile**, and I am having problem solving that.

Here is the sample data.

| OWNER_ID | CREATED_TIME | STATUS_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-07-16 08:29:29.000 | NEW |
| 1 | 2022-02-21 04:38:01.000 | PROCESSED |
| 3 | 2022-02-28 14:24:28.000 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-02-28 14:27:32.000 | CONVERTED |
| 4 | 2022-02-28 14:33:06.000 | NEW |
| 4 | 2022-02-28 14:33:19.000 | IN_PROCESS |
| 5 | 2022-03-01 12:01:48.000 | NEW |
| 5 | 2022-03-01 12:02:00.000 | IN_PROCESS |

This is my query for this.

```
SELECT
    'percentile count' as name,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) within group (order by temp.diff) over () as percentile_90
FROM

(SELECT OWNER_ID,
DATEDIFF(hour,
MIN (CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'NEW' THEN CREATED_TIME END),
MAX (CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'IN_PROCESS' THEN CREATED_TIME END) ) as diff
FROM table
WHERE CREATED_DATE Between DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
AND RESPONSIBLE_ID IN (2731,2727,2702,2730,2701,2699,2696)
GROUP BY OWNER_ID)temp
```

The logic of my problem is to first to get the date difference between STATUS_ID = NEW and STATUS_ID = IN_PROCESS for each OWNER_ID. Then I want to know the overall 90th Percentile of the date differences, returning a single result row.

My desired output is in this format containing just one row:

| Name | 90th Percentile |
| --- | --- |
| Percentile count | 100 |

Comment: Please do not post image. Post sample data and expected result as formatted text

Comment: Though you might get lucky, and someone spots the problem just by looking at the sql, you'll have a much better chance at getting an answer if you post a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue. That includes A) table structure and sample data (CREATE TABLE and insert statements) and B) Expected results  - as text, not images.

Comment: Please use [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to create sample data and your query, and show us exact the outcome you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance guys, I have edited it and is it okay?

Comment: Yes this is better, what is left is to explain the logic to get from the upper table to the desired output

Comment: So for all 8 rows in your sample data, you expect just one row in your desired result ? Are you sure ? What is the use of that ?

Comment: Yes, i just want one row of the data, I want the 90th percentile of the whole dataset and apply it according to the business requirements